# Is there any direct way to give alternate coloring in jquery

Tags: jquery

i mean to say if i can specify anywhere `altRows: true;`

Answer (score 3):

It's easy enough to get the effect you are talking of using core jQuery:

```
$("table tr:even").addClass("alt-row"); // For table rows
$("ul li:even").addClass("alt-row"); // For list items
```

Then you just need the CSS to add a (background) color to all elements with class "alt-row":

```
.alt-row {
   background-color: #aaa;
}
```

If however, you are using a table plugin or similar, then perhaps the plugin provides that option as a configuration property. In that case, check the plugin's documentation.

Comment: yes i tried this but if i reload only grid then it is not getting applied is there any api to do this. I have given pagination when i go for next page its comming without alternate color what do i do?

Comment: @Rinkalkumar, the easiest way is to just run that code again when the table is reloaded. There is the CSS3 `:nth-child` selector which will work "automatically", but it's not well supported yet.

Comment: ya that looks fine but it will not fulfill my requirement any other way if you know

Answer (score 2):

I think you want something like :even (gets 1st, 3rd, 5th and so on elements.  This is because its based on a 0 based index, so 0,2,4,6,...)

```
$(".yourElements:even").css("color","red");
$(".yourElements:odd").css("color","green");
```

All of the sudden its christmas! :), wait that was last week, whoops.

Hope that helps!

Comment: this is ok but how do i add hover style on raw?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think, you have to use CSS.

You can define a css with alterning rows for your table and in your jquery script just add class to your gridview..

Like [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aZebra_Striping_Made_Easy)